# GeckoFX - Wait till the page has loaded with Proxy

Tags: geckofx

I am using this code (VisualBasic) to wait till the page has loaded:

```
Private Sub WaitForPageLoad()
    While (GeckoWebBrowser1.IsBusy)
        Application.DoEvents()
    End While
End Sub
```

It works good but only if there is no proxy. After connecting to proxy (by setting proxies directly in GeckoFX or using external program like Cyberghost) this code completely fails. It "says" that website has been loaded but it is still loading, so program starts to execute next instructions that shouldn't be executed without fully loaded page. 
Does anyone have solution for this? I will be satisfied also with C# code.

Answer (score 0):

Use the document Completed event. The isbusy is not reliable.